# importing package charm : No module named charm

Tags: python, python-import, charm

I excuted a py code  that have an import from charm  as follow : `from charm.toolbox.PKEnc import PKEnc` and I got error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'charm'`

I executed `pip install charm` but I got the following error:

```
Collecting charm
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/6c/6173abe5f27f59f4ce000802a60f8d8d32ad33052391b2c407729b1c7185/charm-1.0b4.zip
Collecting BeautifulSoup
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/40/f2/6c9f2f3e696ee6a1fb0e4d7850617e224ed2b0b1e872110abffeca2a09d4/BeautifulSoup-3.2.2.tar.gz
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: Have you tried to install `BeautifulSoup` first? The error may originate there.

Comment: Yes. When I try to install BeautifulSoup, i get the following error :

Collecting BeautifulSoup
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/40/f2/6c9f2f3e696ee6a1fb0e4d7850617e224ed2b0b1e872110abffeca2a09d4/BeautifulSoup-3.2.2.tar.gz
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: At the moment, we don't have enough information to solve your problem. Can you please find the logs referred to in the error message? Details about your environment (python, pip versions and OS) will also be helpful.

Comment: My code is running using colab notebook. The python version is 3.6.9 . GCC 8.3.0, qnd pip version is 19.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)